# Toothpaste tube parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

A flexible cylindrical tube is [distorted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223447/toothpastesurface-2nd-order-non-linear-pde) by flattening/pinching at one end along radius and leaving the other end circular. So it is isometric to a cylinder.

[image]

Eccentricity is zero at the circular section end and 1 at the pinched end if at all the transitioning sections would be ellipses.

A pde describing a class of developable surfaces is:

$$rt-s^2=0,\quad r= \dfrac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x^2},\;t= \dfrac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial y^2},\; s= \dfrac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x\partial y};$$

It is a second degree Monge-Ampère elliptic partial differential equation.

What is an orthogonal mapping between the cylinder and the Toothpaste tube surface meshes and what is its parametrization ?

Comment: I don't think such an isometry exists (even ignoring the singular behavior at the pinched end). For a right cylinder of height $h$ with boundary circles $A, B$, the distance $d(a, B)$ between $a$ and $B$ is $h$ for all $a \in A$. On the other hand, the distance between the circle at one end of the "toothpaste tube" and the line segment at the other evidently varies.